# JAXB : use local schemaLocation to generate Java classes

Tags: xsd, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to generate Java classes from a XSD schema using the `xjc` command that comes with JAXB.

My schema looks like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns="..." 
           xmlns:ext="http://schemas.myco.com/ext" ... >
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.myco.com/ext" 
             schemaLocation="http://myco.com/schemas/ext.xsd"/>
  ...
```

The problem is that the `schemaLocation` URI does not exist and I can not modify the XSD file.  That is why the generation process fails with errors such as "src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ext:Resource_Type' to a(n) 'type definition' component".

Is there any way to force JAXB to use a local copy of ext.xsd file during the process without modifying the original XSD file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

JAXB Episode File: 
http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2006/09/05/separate-compilation-jaxb-ri-21

or

XML Catalogs (search Google)

Comment: Thank you.  I'll try both.  I didn't know about the first one (I hope it is compatible with jaxb2-maven-plugin), and I've been trying to use a catalog with an entry such as "PUBLIC namespace_url local_path" with no success (any good link in this sense?).  Thanks.

Comment: According to http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide your first proposed alternative seems to work with maven-jaxb2-plugin.  I'll post my results asap.

Comment: It doesn't work.  I've asked it as a new question related to episodic compilation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4510818/jaxb-episodic-compilation-with-maven

Comment: Unfortunately, the [XML Catalogs](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_the_XML_Catalog) defined in Eclipse are not used when runnning "Generate > JAXB Classes" (in a JPA faceted project)

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue ? I think I'm having the similar one, my XSD contains local paths but still it gives src-resolve error. The path is relative in schemaLocation in my case