# jaxb episodic compilation with maven

Tags: java, jaxb, maven, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I am trying to execute the maven-jaxb2-plugin-sample-episode-0.7.4 (explained [here](http://confluence.highsource.org/display/MJIIP/User+Guide) and with a [download available](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-sample-episode/0.7.4/maven-jaxb2-plugin-sample-episode-0.7.4-maven-src.zip)) to try separate schema compilation. Despite it compiles the first schema (A), it fails in the second one (B) because it is not able to resolve the artifact maven-jaxb2-plugin-sample-episode-a-maven:jar:0.7.4.

I execute `mvn assembly:assembly` from the command line (windows) and this is the error I get:

```
...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Maven JAXB 2.x Plugin Sample [episode-b|maven]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [jaxb2:generate {execution: default}]
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-pl
ugin-sample-episode-a-maven/0.7.4/maven-jaxb2-plugin-sample-episode-a-maven-0.7.
4.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-sample
-episode-a-maven:jar:0.7.4' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Could not resolve the artifact.

Embedded error: Missing:
----------
1) org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-sample-episode-a-maven:jar:0.7.4

  Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

  Then, install it using the command:
      mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2 -DartifactId=mav
en-jaxb2-plugin-sample-episode-a-maven -Dversion=0.7.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/p
ath/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:

      mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2 -DartifactId=maven
-jaxb2-plugin-sample-episode-a-maven -Dversion=0.7.4 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/pat
h/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
        1) org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-ample-episode-b-maven:jar:0
.7.4
        2) org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-sample-episode-a-maven:jar:
0.7.4

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact:
  org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin-ample-episode-b-maven:jar:0.7.4

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 8 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Dec 22 16:31:29 CET 2010
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/39M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The example should work as it is so, what am I doing wrong ?  In the real scenario I have more than 10 schemas that have to be compiled as different episodes, so I need the proccess to be automatic (i.e no need to execute "mvn something" for each individual artifact)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module `maven-jaxb2-plugin-ample-episode-b-maven` depends on `maven-jaxb2-plugin-ample-episode-a-maven`.

When `mvn assembly:assembly` is run from the parent folder (which contains the two modules), it builds the jar for `maven-jaxb2-plugin-ample-episode-a-maven`, but **does not install it in your local repository**.

When it then tries to build `maven-jaxb2-plugin-ample-episode-b-maven`, it looks for the dependency (`maven-jaxb2-plugin-ample-episode-a-maven`) and fails to find it in the local repository. Thus the error.

The question is, why would you want to run `mvn assembly:assembly`, which is used to create a binary distribution?  There are no assembly descriptors in either module.

`mvn install` works fine and build both the modules successfully.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try "mvn install" ASAP.  These are my first steps with maven so I suposse I'm still missing some points.  What I finally need is to be able to reference the jars generated by several maven-jaxb2 modules into other third-party projects.